# Data is loss when I use the UNWIND

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-ogm

```
MATCH (ORG:ORG)-[ORGHASPROBLEM:HAS]->(PROBLEM:PROBLEM) WITH PROBLEM,

extract(NUM IN filter( V IN collect({ PROB1:PROBLEM.PROB_ID, PROB2:PROBLEM.REGION}) where V.PROB2= 'LONDON') | NUM.PROB1) AS MEASURES1,

extract(NUM IN filter( V IN collect({ PROB1:PROBLEM.PROB_ID, PROB2:PROBLEM.REGION}) where V.PROB2= 'PARIS') | NUM.PROB1) AS MEASURES2

unwind MEASURES1 AS RESULT1
unwind MEASURES2 AS RESULT2

RETURN DISTINCT PROBLEM.SLAB AS DIMENSION,count(RESULT1) AS  MEASURES1,count(RESULT2) AS MEASURES2
```

---

I am uploading the image of the database and expected output. Can anybody rewrite the query or tell me where I am going wrong?

My question is that MEASURES1 and MEASURES2 have my required data. When I am using the unwind `MEASURES1 AS RESULT1` it give the output as required, but in case of the 2nd unwind (unwind `MEASURES2 AS RESULT2`) it removes the entire data from `MEASURES1` and `MEASURES2`.

Please, see the attached image to understand the scenario more clearly.

[image: Data model, expected output]

Comment: Please avoid sentences as "please reply quickly" and focus on [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please stop trying to ask specific users for help. All assistance is voluntary.

Comment: Your query has syntax errors: `Invalid input '‘': expected whitespace, comment or an expression (line 3, column 100 (offset: 169))
"extract(NUM IN filter( V IN collect({ PROB1:PROBLEM.PROB_ID, PROB2:PROBLEM.REGION}) where V.PROB2= ‘LONDON’) | NUM.PROB1) AS MEASURES1,"`

Comment: @Bruno Peres done with syntax error

Comment: I believe that is a good idea to put a Cypher query in your question to create a initial data set and the expected result over this data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The follow query will get the data out of the database in a way that will allow you to build your report. As a bonus it will also work if you add a new region :

```
MATCH (p:PROBLEM)
WITH count(*) AS ct, p.REGION AS pregion, p.SLAB AS slab
RETURN slab, collect({region: pregion,  count: ct}) as result;
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tom Geudens this worked i am so happy that you spend your precious time to give the answer

Comment: @AkshayVakharia Please mark the answer as accepted if it works for you, so others can see the question is complete! Thanks